# Get last row in pandas HDF5 query

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am trying to get the index of the last row of a pandas dataframe stored in HDF5 **without having to pull the whole dataset or index into memory**. I am looking for something like this:

```
from pandas import HDFStore

store = HDFStore('file.h5')

last_index = store.select('dataset', where='index == -1').index
```

Except in my case the last index won't be `-1` but a `Timestamp`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `start=` and `stop=` arguments which work like positional indexers

```
In [8]: df = DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(10000)},index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10000,freq='s'))

In [9]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [10]: store.append('df',df)

In [11]: nrows = store.get_storer('df').nrows

In [12]: nrows
Out[12]: 10000

In [13]: store.select('df',start=nrows-1,stop=nrows)
Out[13]: 
                            A
2013-01-01 02:46:39 -0.890721

In [15]: df.iloc[[-1]]
Out[15]: 
                            A
2013-01-01 02:46:39 -0.890721
```

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue and the accepted answer seemed like it was a lot of work to get the last row (which should be straightforward). Through some munging, I was able to find something that felt more succinct (to me)

### Set up the Data

```
In [8]: df = DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(10000)},
                        index=pd.date_range('20130101',
                        periods=10000,freq='s'))

In [9]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [10]: store.append('df',df)
```

In fact the last row can be pulled (and index determined) using the following syntax:

### Pull the Last Row (Using `start=-1`)

```
In [11]: store.select('df',start=-1)
                            A
2013-01-01 02:46:39 -0.890721

In [15]: df.iloc[[-1]]
Out[15]: 
                            A
2013-01-01 02:46:39 -0.890721
```

### On Disk Reading

The other reason I like this form of data collection is the same syntax can be used to read "on-disk" files, specifically using [`pd.read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html#pandas.read_hdf).

```
In [16]: s = "path/to/hdfstore/above"
In [17]: pd.read_hdf(s, start=-1)
Out[15]: 
                            A
2013-01-01 02:46:39 -0.890721
```

This is useful as lots of legwork needs to be done with `try, except, finally` when dealing with `HDFStore`, and leveraging on-disk reading methods bypasses those extra requirements in the software engineering phase.

Answer (score -1):

Last index should be

```
last_index  = store['dataset'].index[-1]
```

Comment: edited my post, I need something that doesnt require loading the whole dataset (or index column for that matter) into memory

Comment: Understood, I would look at pytables directly rather than pandas for that.